# Truncate a URL while ignoring DIV tags

Tags: regex, preg-replace, str-replace, substr

We use the following code to display a value in the output of a Wordpress site page. However, occasionally the output is too long to fit within the box we've set for it so we'd like to truncate it.

```
    $markup = str_replace('%%', get_post_meta($post_id, '_sf_submission_field_'.get_the_ID(), true), htmlspecialchars_decode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'markup', true)));

    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $markup);
    $ret = ' ' . $text;
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    $ret = substr($ret, 1);

    echo $ret;
```

Using substr as follows `$ret = substr($ret, 0, 30);` is would be great, however, part of the input string has styling div tags and other text which cannot be truncated. So my question is how can I truncate JUST the part of the string that has a URL in it... and in turn not truncate the href itself as it still needs to be a clickable link.

Here is a sample input string:
`<i class="icon-twitter-squared"></i> http://www.stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl`

...I'd like only the `http://www.stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl` to be truncated to `www.stackoverfl...`
for example - it needs to remain clickable as the original untruncated URL.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you provide an example input string?

Comment: Sure, `<i class="icon-twitter-squared"></i> http://stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl`

Comment: @JoeW can you put a sample string and tell what part you want to be truncated and what not?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the original post.

Comment: @JoeW I answered to your question let me know if that is what you want. Is that's the case tell me what option fits better your needs so I can update the answer to keep it accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** To get the link that is not part of href and also as you asked in the comment you can use this regex:

```
(?<!href=")https?://(.{9}).*?/\w+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zP2zC4/5)**

[image]

Comment: What I need is for the link to remain clickable with the untruncated original URL, but for the 'title' of the link to be shortened to fit in our website format. So for example I'd like the link `http://www.stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl` to point to `http://www.stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl` when clicked, but visually it would show shorter as `www.stackoverflow.com/re...` (for example)

Comment: Basically it's just an aesthetic thing to make the clickable URL fit within the site design. So the text of the link could even be 'link' or 'click here' but the actual URL needs to remain untouched.

Comment: @JoeW I did that in my answer, if you check the last part of the answer it allows you to change the name but not the clickable section. Take a look at the Substitution section here http://regex101.com/r/zP2zC4/4

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't see that bit. OK, however, that URL with a /reallylongurl was probably misleading. The clickable link should be truncated to a maximum of (for example) 9 characters, not just remove anything after a `/`. For example `http://www.stackoverflow.com/reallylongurl` would become `www.stack...`

Comment: @JoeW ok, you can use this link instead http://regex101.com/r/zP2zC4/5 check the substitution section. Btw, if that's what you look for you may consider marking the question as solved :)

Comment: That looks great, exactly the output I'm looking for. Can you advise how to integrate it in my original code snippet?

Comment: @JoeW if you go to the link I sent you and press on `Code generator` you can obtain the code snippet for the regex I provided you. Copy/paste on your code and just adapt the variable names.

Comment: I did that, but Dreamweaver doesn't seem to like the fist line, citing an error. I can't seem to get things moving. Not having much luck here.

Comment: @JoeW I think it's because you need to add `<?php ... ?>` tags. Btw, you should close this answer and ask a new one with that. I answered to your question so for this thread you may consider marking your question as resolved.

Comment: Thanks Fede, although this is already within `<?php ... ?>`. Your answer will certainly be marked as the accepted answer as soon as I've found out what to do with the code you helpfully showed me.